# How to use Sitka (or what is the closest similar font)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I recently discovered [Sitka](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/sitka) and its [design process](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309754147_Sitka_A_collaboration_between_type_design_and_science). **What I'm wondering is how I can use this in LaTeX?**

I've done some searches to find ways/guidance, but the results have been fairly unhelpful:

- I've seen [one person say they're using LuaLaTeX](https://www.reddit.com/r/typography/comments/ixw0tr/any_fans_of_sitka/g6ed9m8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) with an illegal method to get the MS font into the TeX system, but I'm not keen on doing that.
- Questions such as [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/typography-issues/issues/145) don't seem to be answered (at least in any depth), and I can't find a whole lot more information on this question publicly.

If all avenues of importing and using Sitka in LaTeX are illegal, what is the closest font that's freely available? Presently, I use [Charter BT](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/charterbt/), also because it had a fairly decent math symbology library, but I don't really need the math symbols as much any more.

Note I am looking for a solution that could be used with pdfTeX.

Comment: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ may help, if you don't have Windows and can't use `fontspec`: look for the legacy fonts, the items that say Type 1, and/or have `\input XXXX.fd` (font definition files) as their usage.

Answer (score 5):

`pdftex` reads fonts with tfm metric files and at most 256 characters per font, it can not read OpenType fonts at all. To directly read any OpenType font you need to use lualatex or xelatex.

There is nothing illegal about using the Sitka font if you have it (eg if you are on a Windows machine)  eg a basic use with lualatex or xelatex is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Sitka}

\begin{document}

Abc
\end{document}
```

However that's just using the default one size scaled font loading (it actually seems to pick up the Banner size) so a bit of work to setup a fontspec configuration specifying which font name to use in which size range would make better use of the optical scaling.

---

A more complete example using the Heading, display and small versions of the font in suitable ranges

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Sitka}[
BoldFeatures={
FontIndex=1,
SizeFeatures={
{Size=-10, Font=Sitka Small/B},
{Size=10-14, Font=Sitka Text/B},
{Size=14-27, Font=Sitka Heading/B},
{Size=27-, Font=Sitka Banner/B}
}
},
UprightFeatures={
SizeFeatures={
{Size=-10, Font=Sitka Small},
{Size=10-14, Font=Sitka Text},
{Size=14-27, Font=Sitka Heading},
{Size=27-, Font=Sitka Banner}
}
}
]

\begin{document}

\section{this \expandafter\meaning\the\font}
Abc \expandafter\meaning\the\font

\tiny Abc \expandafter\meaning\the\font
\end{document}
```

Comment: @gktscrk I didn't assume that, I simply didn't even notice that tag, I very rarely look at the tags before answering a question as they are useful to narrow down searches to find older posts but it is not useful to use them to guide an answer. I only noticed the pdftex tag after your comment that you had asked for pdftex which I found surprising, so searched the page again and notoced the tagging . But as I say for pdftex there is nothing special to say about sitka, you can't use opentype fonts.

Comment: but I'll add a note to the answer to explicitly note that this isn't pdftex, to match your question edit @gktscrk

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good, and I think I can accept this now.